# kapt compiler issue in studio 3.2.1 with data binding and room

Tags: android, android-room, android-databinding, kapt

Build fails with error "cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent" in all generated binding classes.If I remove the room compiler dependency from my module gradle, then it unable to find room db at run time saying "Db_Impl does not exist".

```
def room_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
//kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
//kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha06"

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:1.1.1" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

// optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:1.1.1"

// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:1.1.1"

// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:1.1.1"

// Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:1.1.1"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
add this dependency into app level gradle file.

```
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

more information refer this link
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing kotlin's annotation processor plugin.  Add this to the top of your app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and uncomment the data binding dependency. Sync after this.